# Use of property viewData in JS view instantiation

Tags: model-view-controller, sapui5

I wonder what the actual use of property **viewData** in JS view instantiation is? What does the corresponding line specify?

```
var oView = sap.ui.view({
        id : "app",
        viewName : "sap.ui.demo.test.view.App",
        type : "JS",
        viewData : { component : this }
    });
```

Thanks, Prasad

Comment: For future readers: JS View is now deprecated. Consider using [Typed View](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/e6bb33d076dc4f23be50c082c271b9f0) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewData  contains user-specific data that is available during the whole lifecycle of the view and the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of a JS view can be found here:
[SAPUI5 SDK API Reference](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.JSView.html#constructor)

it is different from what you have posted. But probably you are referring to the actual components that would reside in the view itself. Probably to start with the developer guide that can be found on the SDK too.

The [walkthrough](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db.html) has a part on views. Hope that can help.